# Graphics.DrawImage OutOFMemory Exception

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net, gdi+, out-of-memory

I'm getting an `OutOfMemory` Exception when trying to resize larger images. Our server can only resize images of less then 1000x1000 pixels. My development machine seems too handle any size, and other developer machines seem to have the same limitations as the server. My development machine is also the best spec'd.

I feel like this code properly disposes of all the objects, but i could be wrong. I've tried using perfmon to view the .Net CLR memory but I'm unsure of how to interpret the results.

I'm stuck as to how to best solve this problem and get a definitive answer on why the problem exists. Any debugging ideas would be greatly appreciated.

Edit: Error occurs on `g.DrawImage`

```
using(Image imgToResize = Image.FromFile(path))
        {
            using (Bitmap b = new Bitmap(ResizeWidth, ResizeHeight, PixelFormat.Format24bppRgb))
            {
                using(Graphics g = Graphics.FromImage(b))
                {
                    g.InterpolationMode = InterpolationMode.HighQualityBicubic;
                    g.DrawImage(imgToResize, 0, 0, ResizeWidth, ResizeHeight);
                    b.Save(DiskPathThumb(maxSize), ImageFormat.Jpeg);
                }
            }
        }
```

Comment: where do you invoke this code, in OnPaint event?

Comment: its invoked post file upload to the server. Sometimes its not even post upload its just when the thumbnail is requested. Either way gives the same result.

Comment: What line is it failing on?  Is it always the same one?  Also, what are the values of ResizeWidth and ResizeHeight? Sometimes GDI+ throws out of memory exceptions for things that aren't really out of memory exceptions.

Comment: sorry, error occurs at `g.DrawImage`, the resize value will usually be quite small. Maybe between 100-300px.

Comment: Some GDI+ functions throws an `OutOfMemory` exception if the parameters are invalid. Though I can't see how that can happen in your code. Since your parameters seem to be always valid. And the doc for your overload of `DrawImages` says nothing about that either.

Comment: Could it be a permissions issue with the value specified in the path variable?  I doubt this is really an OutOfMemoryException.  A 1000 x 1000 image at 24 bpp should only take up about 3 MB in memory.

Comment: so as a test I threw a try catch around this (a while ago in production) and when it exceptions i saved the original file to another folder. Without a doubt everytime the image was > 1000px it would fail. And everytime it was less then it would work. Before i was disposing of these objects the right way i was getting out of memory errors related to permissions. But i'm doubt thats the case anymore.

Comment: @g.foley - Any progress on this? I'm curious about it.

Comment: not yet. the main server i was testing one now seems to be fine. so i'm waiting for a chance to run this on another machine and post results.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out this was somehow related to us using the `SessionPageStatePersister` this was causing our `gen2` stack to rise steadily over time and at some point before the app pool was recycled our systems wasn't able to handle much at all.

We have since reverted to the standard hidden field view state and this error has vanished.

Answer (score 1):

Can you screenshot counters for PrivateBytes, LOH size, #Gen 2 collections?

What type of application is this? How deep is this into your application code? How many objects do you have on the LOH? Since the buffer that is being returned definitely qualifies as a Large Object. Have you looked at the call stack, the state of the heap, and fragmentation when this call fires?

FWIW, you might try the same code in a C or C++ version that uses the GDI. Every one of the graphics related functions you are using is a wrapper around the GDI and testing that in a test application on the failing machines would help narrow things down to the .Net Framework and not something else.

I was not able to get an OOM Exception, but the largest value I could pass was around 19866x19866 before the function would throw an InvalidParameterException. This is on a 64bit Win7 targeting .Net 4 w/VS2010.